A multiplicative calculation for real sets $(0,M)$ and $\emptyset\neq B\subseteq (0,1]$
Let $M$ be a positive real number, $\emptyset\neq B\subseteq (0,1]$,  and put $A:=(0,M)$,
$\beta_0:=\inf B$, and $\beta_1:=\sup B$. Then it is easy to see that $BA=\beta_1 A$
(where $BA:=\{ba: b\in B, a\in A\}$, note that $A, B$ can be considered as two subsets of the multiplicative semigroup of real numbers). Therefore
$$
A\setminus BA=(0,M)\setminus (0,\beta_1M)=
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
 [\beta_1M,M)  \quad : \quad  \beta_1\neq 1 \\
\emptyset  \qquad \qquad\;\;\; : \quad \beta_1=1
\end{array} \right.
$$
We would like to calculate $B(A\setminus BA)$ when $\beta_1\neq 1$. It is easy to see that (by using the above identity)
\begin{equation}
[\beta_1^2M,\beta_1M)\subseteq B(A\setminus BA)=\bigcup_{b\in B}[b\beta_1M,bM)\subseteq [\beta_0\beta_1M,\beta_1M)
\end{equation}
Now,
(1) Can one calculate $B(A\setminus BA)$ in terms of $\beta_0,\beta_1$, and $M$?
(2) $B(A\setminus BA)$ take its most possible case (i.e., $[\beta_0\beta_1M,\beta_1M)$) if $\beta_1^2\leq \beta_0\in B$. Is the converse also true?
(3) Is it true that $B(A\setminus BA)=(\beta_0\beta_1M,M)$) if $\beta_1^2\leq \beta_0\notin B$?
(4) What happens if $\beta_0<\beta_1^2$ (any relation to  $[\beta_0\beta_1M,\beta_0M)$ if $\beta_0\neq 0$)?
(5) When does $B(A\setminus BA)$ take its least possible case (i.e., $[\beta_1^2M,\beta_1M)$)?
Note that the main problem is (1), but (2)-(5) are some of our challenges if (1) is not solved.
